# Want to display server UTC date time regardless of client machines datetime

Tags: javascript

I want to display the current date and time in UTC that the sever works with. How I can force javascript to work with the right date and time! I just want Javascript to show the right dates, in UTC, that the server works with - regardless of what the client's time/date settings are (i.e 12hrs ahead time zone or date set wrongly etc.). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added one js file (date.js) in my aspx page.
And write one function to display the date time.

```
<div id="clock">
</div>

function UpdateUTCDateTime() {
            var currentDate = Date.now();
            var currentUTCdate = currentDate.toUTCString();
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") < 0) {
                currentUTCdate = currentUTCdate.replace("GMT", "UTC");
            }
            $("#Clock").text(Date.parseExact(currentUTCdate, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss UTC").toString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt"));
            setTimeout(UpdateUTCDateTime, (60 - currentDate.getSeconds()) * 1000);
        }
```

So it will give me the Current UTC date time.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the date in UTC

```
var now = new Date(); 
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(),  now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KxYjv/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the datetime of the server while executing javascript on the client, the server will have to dynamically serve its time to the client, either as a separate http request or along with the web page that is calling the javascript.

Comment: can u please elaborate it how to do this?

Comment: Do you know what you are using on the server to create dynamic web pages? JSP, PHP, or ASP.NET?