# Options to display MySQL timestamp in UTC without changing system/server/client timezone

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Is there some MySQL (v 5.7) flag/option I can set during startup/installation or schema creation that displays datetimes and or timestamps in UTC timezone? My system, server and clients are all in US/Pacific time. I am against changing timezones so as not to mess with any other locale-dependent things. I read [18734222](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734222/want-to-display-server-utc-date-time-regardless-of-client-machines-datetime) and [12290317](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290317/how-do-you-get-the-utc-of-a-datetime-field/12290486#12290486) but former question concerns JS and solution to the latter involves a separate `SELECT` statement. I want the UTC time to be displayed when I make a query like `SELECT * from TableName.` I want to avoid, if possible, the additional query for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the system time zone for MySQL Server at startup with the --timezone= option to mysqld_safe or you can also set it by setting the TZ environment variable before you start mysqld.
(but the permissible values for --timezone or TZ are system dependent.)

If you have the SUPER privilege, you can set the global server time zone value at runtime with this statement:
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = ;

So for UTC it will be: 
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+0:00';

For more details, you should probably check the MySQL manual for https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: Sorry, I cant accept this as an answer because, as stated in my question, I want to just *display* the results in UTC without actually changing timezone settings. If you know for sure that changing timezone settings is the only answer, please state so and I'll be happy to accept your answer.